# Can a single PS Plus subscription be used on two different profiles on the same PS4?

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

I have 2 PSN accounts on a ps4 console. The US one has the PS+ subscription, the Asian one has not. Can I play online on the Asia which is not subscribed? Can I also gain trophies on the Asia?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of them.

On PlayStation 4, if the "Main" account of the PS4 has PS+, all other accounts on that device (up to 16, no matter where they says they're located) **can play online**, and you can play any downloaded game on the device no matter with which account you bought/downloaded it with; i.e. I used my asian (secondary) account to download Ace Combat and play it on my US (primary/main) account.

If you use the asian account to play, **you will earn trophies** but in *that* account, not on the US one.

Other thing is, you can't copy the save file for a game from one account to another, well you can copy it to a usb when logged in with asian account for example, and then copy it back on the US account, but you can't use that save file to re-earn those trophies on the US account. I've already tried it, we laughed so hard when we saw a notification stating "You did not earn a trophy" when I tried lo unlock one.

Comment: What if you play from your US account, are you able to earn throphy on your US account?

Comment: Correct! trophies are earned on the same account you're playing in

Answer (score 0):

You can't play Online without a Ps Plus account on the PS4 and you can't gain trophies on that account, without playing trough it.

Comment: but can i play in the asia which has not a ps plus. my US account has ps plus

Comment: but can i play in the asia which has not a ps plus. my US account has ps plus

Answer (score 0):

If the game supports on-line play without PS+ then you can play it. It's up to the developers to require that. Some games allow on-line multiplayer without PS+ but with limited options.

Trophies are related to your profile that is playing the game and have nothing to do with PS+. If you play a US copy of a game on both profiles. Each profile will collect it's own set of trophies based on achievements completed while playing the game from that profile.

Comment: Can I still play online games like Need For Speed in my Asia account which has NOT subscribed PS+. My US account has a PS+

Comment: I don't have that one to test. Just try it and see. At worse it will give you a notice that you need PS+ to go online. That's that's it.